# How do we define atomic radius if we know that the actual scenario is not about discrete shells but of an electron cloud?

Tags: orbitals

What I meant to say is that I've always been confused about the idea of "atomic shells","orbitals",etc...
The main question that I want to highlight is that if we say that orbitals are areas have 90% probability of finding an electron,so how are we so confident about giving precise atomic radius of elements.(Orbitals have different shapes and geometries,so how do we define radius??)

Comment: Do we say that "orbitals are areas have 90% probability of finding an electron"?

Comment: Yes I think it is ZeroTheHero(regarding my current knowledge)...Check out this link and find "90%" on that page(http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/atomorbs.html)

Answer (score 2):

> how are we so confident about giving precise atomic radius of elements?

We aren't confident at all. The attempts that [I've read](http://doi.org/10.1039/b801115j) don't even attempt to claim that it is a fundamental concept, just a useful one.

From the link:

> The atomic radius is not—and cannot be—an intrinsic property of an element. . . there is little hope of defining a theoretically sound atomic radius that is valid for a given element in a wide variety of molecules.

However, it's useful to have a rough estimate of atomic radius, for (say) visualization.

Answer (score 1):

To measure an atomic radius one influence this radius. So depend from the method of measurement one get different radii. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius) counts five different atomic radii:

[image]

> how are we so confident about giving precise atomic radius of elements

We are not. Covalent radii are not the same in tables from different countries:

[image]

[image]

The first image is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius, the last from https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kovalenter_Radius.

Comment: Thanks,appreciate it...but was expecting to hear a bit more precise answer(I know about covalent radius and all...).I lay stress on the idea(or rather confusion)of defining atomic radius when you know about orbitals(I mean how can you define a radius when the orbitals are all distorted and lay in unimaginable shapes)

Comment: Here https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Covalent%20radius are some explanations : "The bond lengths R(AB) are measured by X-ray diffraction (more rarely, neutron diffraction on molecular crystals). Rotational spectroscopy can also give extremely accurate values of bond lengths. For homonuclear A–A bonds, Linus Pauling took the covalent radius to be half the single-bond length in the element, e.g. R(H–H, in H) = 74.14 pm so r(H) = 37.07 pm: in practice, it is usual to obtain an average value from a variety of covalent compounds, although the difference is usually small...

Comment: ...  Sanderson has published a recent set of non-polar covalent radii for the main-group elements,[1] but the availability of large collections of bond lengths, which are more transferable, from the Cambridge Crystallographic Database[2] [3] has rendered covalent radii obsolete in many situations."